How to ensure orderliness in storing and scanning time-series data using HBase?
I want to store and scan my log data. The row key consists of a timestamp and an ID，like id-timestamp.I want to avoid full table scanning and hotspot issues by using this rowkey.
However, when using filterlist to scan id1,id2, their order was not as expected:
id1 t1
id1 t2
...
id2 t1
id2 t2
...

Is there any way to ensure the overall chronological order when I obtain data from multiple IDs? Do I need to first obtain all the log data I want and then sort it by timestamp? or using rowkey timestamp-id to ensure the chronological order?
id1 t1
id2 t1
id1 t2
id2 t2
...

